# Worklight Server6.0 Installation on WAS

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have WAS v8.0.0.3 running on my machine. I've installed worklight server v6.0 on WAS using IBM Installation manager. But using this config, when i try to install a woklight .war of an application and try to access console, it throws an exception.

**Error 500: java.lang.RuntimeException: BaseProjectLocal is null**

From the logs, while accessing application console, this exception comes:

> [8/21/13 3:32:28:986 PDT] 0000008b LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back         due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
>   [8/21/13 3:32:28:997 PDT] 0000008b webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp    logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ServletNameNotFound]: java.lang.RuntimeException: BaseProjectLocal is null
>   at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.get(BaseProjectLocal.java:41)
>   at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal.get(ProjectLocal.java:55)
>   at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal.getCoreBeanFactoryS(ProjectLocal.java:95)
>   at com.worklight.core.util.RssBrokerUtils.getBeanFactory(RssBrokerUtils.java:60)

**While starting the application, this exception comes in logs:**

> [8/21/13 3:37:56:992 PDT] 000000a5 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator.contextInitialized(JeeProjectActivator.java:105)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
>   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
>   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1160)

I fear if something is wrong with installation configuration or database configuration. I'm using mySQL database as backend for worklight. Installation has created Datasource on WAS and test connection also succeeds.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM Installation Manager does not install Worklight into your existing WAS installation.

In Worklight 6.0 all that it currently does, is:

- extract the Worklight framework files and place them in your HD
- extract Ant task scripts

You then need to edit these Ant task scripts with your database and .war information and run them to actually install.

Make sure you read the IBM Worklight 6.0 Information Center at:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_installation.html

Comment: Correct my understanding if wrong, I've been using IBM Installation Manager to install Wroklight server till v5.0.6, and it did install server on existing WAS.

So is it only because of v6.0 that it didn't install on existing WAS? And if so, i still can see IBM_Application_Center app installed on WAS.

And I followed these steps to install worklight server as specified in the link you sent under section **Installing Worklight Server into WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment**.

Comment: Yes, this is new behavior in Worklight 6.0.

Comment: Application Center is separate from Worklight Server.

Comment: I tried running ant script. It gets executed successfully, but it doesn't install war file on WAS. If i manually install war file on server and try to access console, it throws same error.